# geocoder.geocode results cannot be accessed from outside variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am trying to grab google.maps.GeocodeResults so that i can access my address's longitude and latitude so that I can push it to an outside `Array<any>` variable.

Below, I am able to log `results[0]`, but when i try to push it to an array for storage, i am given the status `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, which doesn't make sense to me since i already have the value.

```
 public geocoderResults!: Array<any>;

 public addCodedAddress(address: string): void {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0]) {
                console.log('this does have something in it', results[0]);
                this.geocoderResults.push(results[0]);
                console.log(
                    'this should have something in it, but doesnt ',
                    this.geocoderResults,
                );
            } else {
                console.warn(
                    'Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +
                        status,
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

How can i access these GeocodeResults so i can grab their long / lat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually initialize your `geocoderResults` class field:

```
public geocoderResults: any[] = [];
```